Where are Azure Web App Configuration Metadata Properties Documented
Background
I've been working on updates to Azure Web App settings (of various categories) such as the runtime version, the stack, etc.
I've been doing this work in Bicep.
These settings seem to be generally distributed across different resource types/levels such as:

'Microsoft.Web/sites@API_version'
'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@API_version'
'Microsoft.Web/sites/config/appsettings@API_version'

Issue
I am struggling to find a list of the properties available in the metadata for the web application resource. See the "properties" object in the sample Bicep below:
resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'metadata'
  kind: 'string'
  parent: resourceSymbolicName
  properties: {}
}

If you go to the documentation site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-metadata?pivots=deployment-language-bicep
There are no indications what those properties might be. I researched for possible JSON schema for the type among other things, and no luck.
I know one metadata property I needed and used was the CURRENT_STACK.
Another usage example for this metadata is as the following:
resource appServiceApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'appServiceApp'
  location: 'region'
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 'appServiceName')
    siteConfig: {
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v8.0'
      metadata: [
        {
          name: 'CURRENT_STACK'
          value: 'dotnet'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Where this metadata properties are documented?

Is this what you're looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings

You should be able to get quite a comprehensive list here:
Microsoft Learn - App Service Settings

@Fastnlight I appreciate your comment. I don't think the principle of caching applies here, since the settings available can change over time. The link is to MS Learn, also, which is a reliable source.

@Fastnlight There are hundreds settings, dozens of setting groups, and runtime/language specific settings which are different depending on too many factors to describe in a SO answer. The question was where are the properties documented, not what are the properties. And for very good reason.

That page is not the right place. It has no reference to "CURRENT_STACK" anyway and I know for a fact that is a property of metadata since I posted it in my example and I have used it myself and you can find it online. I researched this thoroughly and even viewed the JSON schema definition for Web/Metadata (using latest schema I could find here https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/main/schemas/2023-01-01/Microsoft.Web.json ). Even here "Metadata" (line 10063) is just plain key/value pairs.

@YousefImran Yeah. Microsoft need to make some amendments. But as far as I can tell, this is the best list you can get right now.

thank you sir. I'll dwell onto it.

I think what you want is REST API responsible for each operation. Please note that CRUD operations has different REST APIs.
In the given code snippet for metadata which is for site config and you can very well refer here:
Create or update properties
web app metadata

If you search those pages, none of them have a reference to "CURRENT_STACK" and I know for a fact that is a property of metadata since I posted it in my example and I have used it myself and you can find it online. Also web app "Configuration" (first link) is different from "Metadata". I researched this thoroughly and even view the JSON schema definition for Web/Metadata (using latest schema I could find here https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/main/schemas/2023-01-01/Microsoft.Web.json ). Even here "Metadata" (line 10063) is just plain key/value pairs.
